# Highlight entire row based on Conditional Formatting

Tags: vba, excel

**THE BACKGROUND**

I'm writing a Sub to audit a report that is received daily. It is meant to check for blanks in 3 columns and duplicates in a fourth, then delete all rows that did not have an issue (i.e. no duplicates, no blanks).

Blanks are found in each row with:

```
lRow = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set MR = Range("D1:D" & lRow)
For Each cell In MR
If cell.Value = "" Then cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
Next

Set MR = Range("E1:E" & lRow)
For Each cell In MR
If cell.Value = "" Then cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
Next

Set MR = Range("M1:M" & lRow)
For Each cell In MR
If cell.Value = "" Then cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
Next
```

And duplicates by Conditional Formatting here:

```
   Columns("J:J").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

---

**THE PROBLEM**

The code that I am using to delete "non-issue" rows only keeps rows whose entire row has a fill. The conditional formatting for duplicates does not allow for highlighting of more than just the cell, to my knowledge.

To solve this, I tried to use some code to find cells with the conditional formatting fill (`ColorIndex 38`), and fill the entire row, but it seems that the CF does not actually fill the cell as `MsgBox Selection.Interior.ColorIndex` returns "-4142" (`NoFill`).

---

**THE QUESTION**

How can I either:

- Identify conditionally formatted cells and fill the entire row?

or

- Remove only rows that do not contain a single cell that is filled?

Comment: For CF Color use: `MsgBox Selection.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex`

Comment: Hi @Fadi, thanks for the input. I tried that to no avail (noted under "The Problem")

Comment: CF Color and cell's format will conflict.Clear CF Color and try again.

Comment: I think @Fadi comment should work. Note the `.DisplayFormat` makes it different to what you noted under "The Problem", but only works from Excel 2010

Comment: Probably you can name the ranges in Selection and preserve these names in an array. Use Selection.Area for the ranges. Then later iterate through the named ranges and do the stuff with them.